# Ensuring consistent formatting for tabular

Tags: tables, macros

In my document I have many tables on the format

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l||l}
    a & b & W\\ \hline
    c & d & g\\ 
    e & f & g\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

The number of columns might vary, as can the number of rows but I always want to have a double line separating the rightmost column from the others and a line separating the first and second rows.

Is there some way that I can write a custom command allowing me to write something along the lines of

```
\begin{tabular2}{3}
    a & b & W\\
    c & d & g\\ 
    e & f & g\\ 
\end{tabular2}
```

For the same result?

This is so that I can ensure that I haven't made minor formatting errors changes in any of my many tables

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which engine are you using? pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex?

Comment: What should be the formatting of say 4 columns? Should it be `{l|ll||l}` or `{l|l|l||l}`? Are there always at least 3 columns? What should happen if there are less?

Comment: @Skillmon
{||l} for the case of only one column. {l|l|l||l} for 4. There is always at least one column and one row.

Comment: @TeXnician pdflatex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `xparse` (see edit history for versions prior to 2019-03-05):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bomaztab}{ O{c} m +b }
 {
  \bomaz_maketable:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
 {}

\tl_new:N \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl
\seq_new:N \l_bomaz_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bomaz_maketable:nnn
 {
  % #1 = alignment argument, #2 = number of cols, #3 = body
  % add #2-1 'l|' cols
  \tl_set:Nx \l_bomaz_preamble_tl { \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 }{ l| } }
  % add a trailing '|l'
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_bomaz_preamble_tl { |l }
  % split the body at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bomaz_body_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  % detach the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_bomaz_body_seq \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl
  % start the tabular
  \bomaz_tabular:nV { #1 } \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
  % first row is followed by \hline
  \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl \\ \hline
  % deliver the other rows
  \seq_use:Nn \l_bomaz_body_seq { \\ }
  % end the tabular
  \endtabular
 }

% helper function to be varied (start of tabular)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bomaz_tabular:nn { \tabular[#1]{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bomaz_tabular:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bomaztab}{3}
    a & b & W\\
    c & d & g\\ 
    e & f & g\\ 
\end{bomaztab}
\qquad
\begin{bomaztab}{2}
    a & W \\
    c & g \\ 
    e & g \\ 
\end{bomaztab}

\medskip

XYZ
\begin{bomaztab}[t]{2}
    a & W \\
    c & g \\ 
    e & g \\ 
\end{bomaztab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different implementation where the number of columns is guessed from the first row; however, columns with different alignments can be specified explicitly, see the last example; also the vertical alignment can be set independently.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bomaztab}{ O{} +b }
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_bomaz_guess_bool
  \keys_set:nn { bomaz/tables }
   {
    valign=c,
    #1
   }
  \bomaz_maketable:VVn \l_bomaz_align_tl \l_bomaz_preamble_tl { #2 }
 }
 {}

\bool_new:N \l_bomaz_guess_bool
\tl_new:N \l_bomaz_align_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl
\seq_new:N \l_bomaz_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l__bomaz_preamble_seq
\seq_new:N \l__bomaz_temp_seq

\keys_define:nn { bomaz/tables }
 {
  valign .tl_set:N = \l_bomaz_align_tl,
  preamble .code:n =
   {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_bomaz_guess_bool
    \tl_set:Nn \l_bomaz_preamble_tl { #1 }
   },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bomaz_maketable:nnn
 {
  % #1 = alignment argument, #2 = preamble, #3 = body
  % split the body at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bomaz_body_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  % detach the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_bomaz_body_seq \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl
  \bool_if:NT \l_bomaz_guess_bool
   {
    \__bomaz_preamble_guess:
   }
  \__bomaz_preamble_compute:
  % start the tabular
  \bomaz_tabular:nV { #1 } \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
  % first row is followed by \hline
  \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl \\ \hline
  % deliver the other rows
  \seq_use:Nn \l_bomaz_body_seq { \\ }
  % end the tabular
  \endtabular
 }

% helper function to be varied (start of tabular)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bomaz_tabular:nn { \tabular[#1]{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bomaz_tabular:nn { nV }
% variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bomaz_maketable:nnn { VVn }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bomaz_preamble_guess:
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__bomaz_temp_seq { & } \l_bomaz_firstrow_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__bomaz_temp_seq } { l }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bomaz_preamble_compute:
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__bomaz_preamble_seq { } \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_bomaz_preamble_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__bomaz_preamble_seq { || } { | } { || }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bomaztab}
    a & b & W\\
    c & d & g\\ 
    e & f & g\\ 
\end{bomaztab}
\qquad
\begin{bomaztab}
    a & W \\
    c & g \\ 
    e & g \\ 
\end{bomaztab}

\medskip

XYZ
\begin{bomaztab}[valign=t,preamble=rl]
    aaa & WWW \\
    cc & gg \\ 
    e & ggg \\ 
\end{bomaztab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `expl3` and `environ` you could as well parse the number of columns... Just saying :)

Comment: @Skillmon Do you mean calling `\begin{bomaztab}{ccrllc}` and get the equivalent of `\begin{tabular}{c|c|r|l|l||c}`?

Comment: No I meant you should just have to call `\begin{bomaztab}` and it knows the correct amount of columns (with the option to give it the correct amount of columns for edge cases where the alignment tab character might be hidden inside unexpandable macros).

Comment: @Skillmon That's a nice idea, let me work it out (train is 30 minutes late and the lounge has WiFi).

Comment: @Skillmon New implementation on-line.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like the following. Notice that the method to put a `\hline` under the first row is not pretty, imho.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcount\tabtwocnt

\makeatletter
\newenvironment*{tabular2}[2][]
{%
  \def\tabtwotmpa{\begin{tabular}[#1]}%
  \ifnum#2=1\relax%
    \def\tabtwotmpb{||l}
  \else%
    \def\tabtwotmpb{}
    \tabtwocnt=1\relax%
    \loop%
      \edef\tabtwotmpb{\tabtwotmpb l|}%
      \advance\tabtwocnt by 1\relax%
      \ifnum\tabtwocnt<#2\relax%
    \repeat%
    \edef\tabtwotmpb{\tabtwotmpb|l}
  \fi%
  \global\let\tabtwotmpc\\
  \expandafter\tabtwotmpa\expandafter{\tabtwotmpb}%
  \global\let\tabtwotmpd\\%
  \gdef\\{\global\let\\\tabtwotmpd\\\hline}\@firstofone%
}{%
  \end{tabular}
  \global\let\\\tabtwotmpc
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular2}[]{1}
  a
\end{tabular2}
\begin{tabular2}[]{2}
  a & b
\end{tabular2}
\begin{tabular2}[]{3}
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f
\end{tabular2}
\begin{tabular2}[]{4}
  a & b & c & z\\
  d & e & f & z
\end{tabular2}
\begin{tabular2}[]{5}
  a & b & c & y &z\\
  d & e & f & y &z
\end{tabular2}
\begin{tabular2}[]{12}
  a & b & c & y & z & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
  a & b & c & y & z & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
  a & b & c & y & z & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
\end{tabular2}
Foo\\Bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `listofitems` and token lists.  No number-of-columns argument is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\newtoks\tabAtoks
\newtoks\tabAhead
\newcommand\apptotoks[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\NewEnviron{tabularA}[1][c]{%
  \setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \readlist\tabA{\BODY}%
  \tabAtoks{}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\tabA[]{%
    \ifnum\listlen\tabA[\icnt]>1\relax%
      \tabAhead{}%
      \foreachitem\j\in\tabA[\icnt]{%
        \ifnum\jcnt=1\relax\else\apptotoks\tabAhead{|}\fi%
        \ifnum\jcnt=\listlen\tabA[\icnt]\relax\apptotoks\tabAhead{|}\fi%
        \apptotoks\tabAhead{l}%
        \ifnum\jcnt=1\relax\else\apptotoks\tabAtoks{&}\fi%
        \expandafter\apptotoks\expandafter\tabAtoks\expandafter{\j}%
      }%
      \ifnum\icnt<\listlen\tabA[]\relax\apptotoks\tabAtoks{\\}\fi%
      \ifnum\icnt=1\relax\apptotoks\tabAtoks{\hline}\fi%
    \fi%
  }%
  \def\tmp{\begin{tabular}[#1]}
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\tabAhead}%
  \the\tabAtoks
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularA}
    a & b & W\\
    c & d & g\\ 
    e & f & g\\
\end{tabularA}
\qquad
\begin{tabularA}
    a & W \\
    c & g \\ 
    e & g \\
\end{tabularA}

\medskip

XYZ
\begin{tabularA}[t]
    a & W \\
    c & g \\ 
    e & g \\
\end{tabularA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do precisely this using TeXstudio's macros, and I imagine most editors have a similar macro or snippet functionality.

In TeXstudio, it's as simple as pasting your code into a box and assigning it a name:

- Go to `Macros` > `Edit Macros`.
- Click the `Add` button.
- Put your table template text in the `LaTeX Content` field, selecting `Type` = `Normal`.
- Put the name you want to appear on the TeXstudio menu in the `Name` field.
- Optionally, you can define trigger text (`Trigger` field) which, when typed, will insert your table template.

To use it, go to the `Macros` menu in TeXstudio and select the name you added to the `Name` field above.

In the case of frequently used items, I also assign a shortcut key combination, so inserting, say, a table or figure or section header is as easy as `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`T` or whatever:

- Go to `Options` > `Configure TeXstudio...`.
- Select the `Shortcuts` tab.
- Go to the entry for the `Macro` menu.
- Expand it and select the macro you just created.
- Double click in the `Current Shortcut` field, press your desired key combination, and hit `ENTER`.

Note that in TeXstudio, shortcuts seem to be positional: if you assign `CTRL`+`Q` to your second macro, "Insert Cool Stuff", and then move this macro elsewhere in the editable list, `CTRL`+`Q` will activate whatever ends up being in the second position in your macro list, and not "Insert Cool Stuff". This is an odd design choice, so you should be aware of it.

I realize you were looking at using a Latex macro (i.e. `\newcommand\whatever`) for this purpose, but as is so often the case, Latex makes the impossible easy and the easy excruciating, only solvable through a profound understanding of ancient programming, or both.

Your editor has no such problems ;-)

(EDIT: Considering the plethora of packages --thousands of lines of code, *at least*-- which have been written just to get basic table functionality to work right in Latex (by-row formatting, multi-columns, expanding cells, vertical alignment settings, and even that most basic of all functions, *text wrapping*, which worked just fine on my Atari 800 without any hacks), I stand by my statement about having to have a deep knowledge of ancient programming to do what is easy in other software (and any language that treats `_` as a reserved character is ancient, if not pre-historic). That doesn't mean Latex is bad, but it is perhaps the single most arcane thing anyone not working on legacy bank mainframes will ever come across).

Comment: (a) There's no need for "ancient programming" (if you do not like TeX, try the very recent "expl3". (b) Answers should provide some details. How did you achieve a TeXstudio macro for arbitrary column numbers etc.? That would be a point to start.

Comment: @TeXnician Actually, and in spite of the other answers that have been given here, I'd say there's no need for programming of *any* type in this case. We're talking, essentially, about pasting a few code snippets into the editor -- most editors excel at this, and there's absolutely no need for scores of lines of code like `\def\tabtwotmpa{\begin{tabular}[#1]}%`!

Comment: Will this work for an arbitrary number of columns, like the other answers do?

Comment: @GilWilliams `\begin{tabular2}{12}` works just fine on my machine. My code works for an arbitrary number of columns (as long as TeX's capacities are not superseded).

Comment: @GilWilliams Both `\begin{tabular2}[]{8}` or `\begin{bomaztab}{12}` work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Skillmon Okay, I see what you're doing now -- this applies the formatting the OP requested to a table of n columns, assuming you manually create a table with the same number of columns first. I was assuming it generated the table, too, or at least a few rows with n columns each. Could that even be done? Can Latex do constructs like the following pseudocode: `for row = 1 to n; while row {print $ycolumnrow}`?

Comment: @GilWilliams how should I generate a table, if I don't know the contents. The `a & b & c` are just placeholders and not the final contents.

Comment: @Skillmon Those placeholders are all you need to make it easy to work with the table (well, easy as defined in Latex!). They're sort of the equivalent of empty cells in a spreadsheet. That would be extreeeeeemely convenient and powerful!

Comment: @GilWilliams and how should TeX source code generate source code in the same file without a TeX-run (with a TeX-run would be hard enough)? Of course you can write code that iterates an integer. It's used in my answer. In TeX-pseudo-code: `\loop\doStuff\advance\count by 1\relax\ifnum\count<\endcount\relax\repeat`

Comment: @Skillmon Ah, that's the gotcha, right! This could, however, be done with TeXstudio's macros, which allow you to use Javascript (or a subset thereof). It would be a sort of customizable table-generating wizard. Pity I don't know Javascript!

Comment: @GilWilliams and this is superior because of? That's not a gotcha, that is like saying C is the worst programming language because it has to be compiled. Inserting a `&` or `\\ ` is (or might be) faster than mouse-navigating through a wizard if you know what should be in the table.

Comment: @Skillmon The "gotcha" isn't a failure of Latex, it was me being caught by a pretty obvious problem that I needed you to point out to me. As to making a wizard that would generate arbitrary-sized tables with custom formatting, hitting a key combo and typing `3` (cols) `12` (rows) would be far faster than typing. But more importantly, it would eliminate a source of human error, insuring consistency. To this day, the best way to get *complex* tables into Latex is to create them in Excel and use a package whose name eludes me to export them to Latex format. And I really wish that wasn't the case.